# Inequality of sum of error functions

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, error-function

I am stuck with proving the following. Let $A\geq0
, B>0$, and $\alpha \in (0,1)$. I would like to show that
$$
\text{erf}\left(\frac{\alpha A+x}{\sqrt{2} \alpha  B}\right)+\text{erf}\left(\frac{A-x}{\sqrt{2} B}\right)-\text{erf}\left(\frac{\alpha A-x}{\sqrt{2} \alpha  B}\right)-\text{erf}\left(\frac{A+x}{\sqrt{2} B}\right)\geq 0,\quad \mbox{for all } x\geq0,$$ where erf($\cdot$) denotes the error function.

In my numerical experiments I have not found a single counterexample for this inequality, but I have not been able yet to prove it (e.g., via known bounds for the error function). Anyone a clue?

Comment: WLOG, $\sqrt 2B=1$. Study the growth of $\text{erf}(A+\lambda x)+\text{erf}(A- x)$ where $\lambda>1$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, thanks for the hint. I looked at the derivative (I assume you mean that by growth) of $$f(x) =\text{erf}(A+\lambda x)-\text{erf}(A+x) +\text{erf}(A- x) - \text{erf}(A-\lambda x)$$ for $\lambda>1$. I know that $f(0)=0$, $f'(0)\geq 0$ and that $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty = 0}f(x)$, but further than that I cannot push it. Is this the direction that you suggest?

Comment: This is not exactly what I suggested...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $C = \frac{A}{B\sqrt{2}}$, $y = \frac{x}{B \sqrt{2}}$ and $u = \frac{1}{\alpha} > 1$.
We need to prove that
$$\mathrm{erf}(C + uy) + \mathrm{erf}(C - y) - \mathrm{erf}(C - uy) - \mathrm{erf}(C + y)
\ge 0, \ \forall y \ge 0.$$

Let
$$f(u) = \mathrm{erf}(C + uy) + \mathrm{erf}(C - y) - \mathrm{erf}(C - uy) - \mathrm{erf}(C + y).$$
We have
$$f'(u) = \frac{2y}{\sqrt{\pi}} \mathrm{e}^{-(C+uy)^2} + \frac{2y}{\sqrt{\pi}} \mathrm{e}^{-(C - uy)^2} \ge 0.$$
Also, $f(1) = 0$. Thus, $f(u)\ge 0$ for all $u \ge 1$.

We are done.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! A quick question (perhaps I am missing something or I do not fully comprehend your answer); why are you taking the derivative with respect to $u$? Are you allowed to say that if $f(u)\geq 0$ (as you define it) for all $u\geq0$ that the original expression is non-negative for all $y\geq 0$, while the transformation of $u$ does not involve $y$?

Comment: @mathlay Note that $f(1) = 0$. If $y > 0$, then $f(u)  < 0$ for $u \in (0, 1)$. I just proved that for any $C\ge 0, y\ge 0$, it holds that $f(u) \ge 0$ for any $u\ge 1$.

Comment: Ah yes, I see. Thank you very much!

Comment: @mathlay You are welcome.

Comment: Can we say something about the inequality if we change the two $\alpha$'s in the denominator to $\sqrt{\alpha}$ (and leave the two $\alpha$'s in the numerator),  I tried using your approach, but the derivative of $f(u)$ does not give you a definitive answer. Perhaps there is then a root, but I am not sure yet.

Comment: @mathlay  $f(u) = \mathrm{erf}(C/u + uy) + \mathrm{erf}(C-y) - \mathrm{erf}(C/u - uy) - \mathrm{erf}(C+y)$,
$f'(u) \ge 0$, $f(1) = 0$. Did you use software to simplify $f'(u)$?

Answer (score 0):

@Yves Daoust gave the good hint.

Keeping your notations, at least small values of the arguments, we have for the expression
$$f(x)=2 \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }}\,\frac {(1-\alpha)}{\alpha B}\,e^{-\frac{A^2}{2 B^2}}\,  \Bigg[1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{ a_n}{(2 n+1)! \,\left(\alpha  B^2\right)^{2 n} }\, x^{2n}\Bigg]\,x$$ with
$$a_1=\left(\alpha ^2+\alpha +1\right) (A^2-B^2) $$
$$a_2=\left(\alpha ^4+\alpha ^3+\alpha ^2+\alpha +1\right) \left(A^4-6 A^2 B^2+3 B^4\right)$$
$$a_2=\left(\alpha ^6+\alpha ^5+\alpha ^4+\alpha ^3+\alpha ^2+\alpha +1\right) \left(A^6-15 A^4 B^2+45 A^2 B^4-15 B^6\right)$$

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Did you derive the expression via the Maclaurin series for the error function? I tried to derive it myself, but got lost in the coefficients. Finally, how can you then conclude from this that indeed $f(x)\geq 0$ for all $x\geq0$?

Comment: @mathlay. Yes for MacLaurin. I kept (on purpose) your notations to show the complexity. Avoid multiple constants just as River Li did.